# Vector Subscript Out of Range Line 1501

Tags: c++, vector, graph

I am trying to read data from file, and making a graph from it. The code I wrote in normal functional programming is fine. When I am trying to convert it in object oriented programming approach, It is giving error. This is my functional programming code.

```cpp
struct Edge {
    int src, dest, weight;
};

vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> MakeGraph(int noOfVerticies, vector<Edge> const& edges)
{
    vector<vector<pair<int,int>>> adjList;
    adjList.resize(noOfVerticies);

    for (auto& edge : edges)
    {
        int src = edge.src;
        int dest = edge.dest;
        int weight = edge.weight;

        // insert at the end
        adjList[src].push_back(make_pair(dest, weight));
    }

    return adjList;
}

void printGraph(vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> adjList , int N)
{
    //cout << N;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        // print all neighboring vertices of given vertex
        for (pair<int, int> v : adjList[i])
            cout << "(" << i << ", " << v.first <<
            ", " << v.second << ") ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> readAndMakeGraph()
{
    Edge e1;
    int noOfvertices;
    bool isFirst = false;
    ifstream inFile("a1.txt");
    char ch;
    vector <Edge> v1;
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        if (isFirst == false)
        {
            inFile >> ch;
            noOfvertices = static_cast<int>(ch)-48;
            isFirst = true;
            //cout << noOfvertices;
        }
        else
        {
            inFile >> ch;
            e1.src = static_cast<int>(ch) - 48;
            inFile >> ch;
            e1.dest = static_cast<int>(ch) - 48;
            inFile >> ch;
            e1.weight = static_cast<int>(ch) - 48;
            v1.push_back({ e1.src, e1.dest,e1.weight });
        }
        
    }
    inFile.close();

    vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> a1 = MakeGraph(noOfvertices, v1);

    printGraph(a1, noOfvertices);
    return a1;
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> a1;

    a1 = readAndMakeGraph();

}
```

File Format is

```
noOfVertices
src, dest, weight
src, dest, weight
```

Now My Object Oriented Code is

> Graph.cpp

```cpp
#include "Graph.h"
void Graph::MakeGraph(vector<Edge> const& edges)
{
    vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> adjList;
    adjList.resize(noOfVertices);

    for (auto& edge : edges)
    {
        int src = edge.src;
        int dest = edge.dest;
        int weight = edge.weight;

        // insert at the end
        adjList[src].push_back(make_pair(dest, weight));
    }

}

void Graph::printGraph()
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfVertices; i++)
    {
        // print all neighboring vertices of given vertex
        for (pair<int, int> v : adjList[i])
            cout << "[" << i << ", " << v.first <<
            ", " << v.second << "] ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    
}

void Graph:: readAndMakeGraph()
{
    Edge e1;
    int noOfvertices;
    bool isFirst = false;
    ifstream inFile("a1.txt");
    char ch;
    vector <Edge> v1;
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        if (isFirst == false)
        {
            inFile >> ch;
            noOfvertices = static_cast<int>(ch) - 48;
            isFirst = true;
            //cout << noOfvertices;
        }
        else
        {
            inFile >> ch;
            e1.src = static_cast<int>(ch) - 48;
            inFile >> ch;
            e1.dest = static_cast<int>(ch) - 48;
            inFile >> ch;
            e1.weight = static_cast<int>(ch) - 48;
            v1.push_back({ e1.src, e1.dest,e1.weight });
        }

    }
    inFile.close();

    MakeGraph(v1);


}
```

> Graph.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct Edge {
    int src, dest, weight;
};
class Graph
{
    vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> adjList;
    int noOfVertices;
public:
    void MakeGraph(vector<Edge> const& edges);
    void printGraph();
    void readAndMakeGraph();
    
};
```

And my main is

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "Graph.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Graph h1;
    
    h1.readAndMakeGraph();
    h1.printGraph();


}
```

I am getting this runtime error.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `Graph::readAndMakeGraph`, you define a function-local variable `int noOfVertices` which is *different* from the Graph member variable `Graph::noOfVertices`. Later, when you call `printGraph`, it's looking at the latter, which never got initialized.

If you just remove the line `int noOfVertices;` from that function, it should address the immediate issue.

The same issue occurs in `Graph::MakeGraph`, which declares a function-local variable `adjList`. Then, `printGraph` is looking at `Graph::adjList`, which never got set.

Comment: Thanks. Now I am having error in  `Graph::printGraph`, the statement is `Unhandled exception at 0x7CB2F2F6 (ucrtbased.dll) in graph last question.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.`

Comment: Looks like there's the same issue with `MakeGraph` defining a function-local version of `adjList`, meaning that `printGraph` is acting on `Graph::adjList` which also isn't initialized.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan You saved my Day. Add this in your answer, And I will tick it.